How to Retrieve Token Metadata in 2024?
What is the simplest way to retrieve token metadata such as name, symbol, and decimals in 2024?

The @solana/spl-token-registry is deprecated and lacks new tokens.
The @metaplex-foundation/mpl-token-metadata has been updated from version 2 to version 3, resulting in complex dependencies to obtain minimal token information.

For example, tokens:

2b1kV6DkPAnxd5ixfnxCpjxmKwqjjaYmCZfHsFu24GXo - PYUSD
Es9vMFrzaCERmJfrF4H2FYD4KCoNkY11McCe8BenwNYB - USDT


The recommended way from Metaplex is to use UMI to compose your fetches since the old library @metaplex-foundation/mpl-token-metadata has been deprecated.
UMI fetch assets
To fetch using the mint you'll use the method
import { fetchDigitalAsset } from '@metaplex-foundation/mpl-token-metadata'
import { createUmi } from "@metaplex-foundation/umi-bundle-defaults";
import {
    keypairIdentity,
    publicKey
} from "@metaplex-foundation/umi";
import { walletAdapterIdentity } from "@metaplex-foundation/umi-signer-wallet-adapters";
import { dasApi } from "@metaplex-foundation/digital-asset-standard-api";

// // you can initialize umi using the following ways 
// initializing umi using a keypair
const keypair = umi.eddsa.createKeypairFromSecretKey(
    Uint8Array.from([]) 
);

umi.use(keypairIdentity(keypair)).use(mplTokenMetadata()).use(dasApi());

// // initializing using the wallet adapter
//  const umi = createUmi("https://api.devnet.solana.com")
//    .use(walletAdapterIdentity(signer))
//    .use(mplTokenMetadata());

const mint = publicKey("7j8dyfBUPYvE3BVBNMWQ8geXYosQTsPaAnExndYTb9XV");
const asset = await fetchDigitalAsset(umi, mint);

const {
    metadata: { name, symbol },
    mint: { decimals },
} = asset;

The above method will return the token details together with the metadata as defined by the  Digital Asset standard, read more here
You will retrieve the details you need from the nested metadata and mint object
Note that the above fetch will not return the token owner details and should you require them, you need to use the digital asset with token methods which returns details about the owner of the asset.
DAS API
The second method you can use is using the DAS API and making a request to an  RPC provider that supports it
const fetchUsingDAS = async () => {
    const collectible = await umi.rpc.getAsset(
        publicKey("7j8dyfBUPYvE3BVBNMWQ8geXYosQTsPaAnExndYTb9XV")
    );

    const {
        content: {
            metadata: { name, symbol },
        },
        //@ts-ignore
        token_info: { decimals },
    } = collectible;
    console.log(decimals);
};

fetchUsingDAS()
    .then(() => console.log("success: "))
    .catch((error) => console.error(error));
 
## TOKEN 22

For token 22 SPL tokens that use the metadata pointer extension you can use the `getMetadata` helper method to query for these details 

```typescript
import { getTokenMetadata } from "@solana/spl-token";

const metadata = await getTokenMetadata(
  connection,
  mint, // Mint Account address
);

ref: https://solana.com/developers/guides/token-extensions/metadata-pointer
getting decimals
To get the token decimals alternatively, you can make an RPC call through the getMint methods which fetches the onchain mint account data and returns a deserialized JSON outpu
async function getDecimals() {
    let mint = new PublicKey("3MoHgE6bJ2Ak1tEvTt5SVgSN2oXiwt6Gk5s6wbBxdmmN");

    const connection = new Connection(clusterApiUrl("devnet"));
    const decimals = await (
        await getMint(connection, mint)
    )?.decimals;

    console.log(mint);
}

getDecimals().then().catch(console.error);


5 modules for getting simple data, web3 is cursed...
@metaplex-foundation/js is deprecated

the old package is usable, you'll have to install it locked at version 2
